# Checkbox onChange not fired

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a checkbox, but when I check on it, the onChange method is not fired. It does not print "Test"

```
<CheckBox
   value="Test"
   onChange={e => {
      console.log('Test');
   }}
>
```

my full code:

```
const CheckboxGroup = Checkbox.Group;

...

<CheckboxGroup>
        <QuestionCheckBox
          value="31"
          onChange={() => {
            console.log('Test');
          }}
        >
          <FormattedMessage id="SE-196.PopUp6.Question.31" />
        </QuestionCheckBox>
        <QuestionCheckBox value="32">
          <FormattedMessage id="SE-196.PopUp6.Question.32" />
        </QuestionCheckBox>
        <QuestionCheckBox value="33">
          <FormattedMessage id="SE-196.PopUp6.Question.33" />
        </QuestionCheckBox>
        <QuestionCheckBox value="34">
          <FormattedMessage id="SE-196.PopUp6.Question.34" />
        </QuestionCheckBox>
      </CheckboxGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wrapping the `checkBoxes` with `CheckboxGroup` you need to put `onChange` to `CheckboxGroup`

Then you need to create a new state called `checked`

```
<CheckboxGroup onChange={value => this.setState({checked: value})}>
        <QuestionCheckBox value="31">
        {this.state.checked.indexOf('31') !== -1 ?
          <FormattedMessage id="SE-196.PopUp6.Question.31" />: null}
        </QuestionCheckBox>
        <QuestionCheckBox value="32">
        {this.state.checked.indexOf('32') !== -1 ?
          <FormattedMessage id="SE-196.PopUp6.Question.32" />: null}
        </QuestionCheckBox>
        <QuestionCheckBox value="33">
         {this.state.checked.indexOf('33') !== -1 ?
          <FormattedMessage id="SE-196.PopUp6.Question.33" />: null}
        </QuestionCheckBox>
        <QuestionCheckBox value="34">
         {this.state.checked.indexOf('34') !== -1 ?
          <FormattedMessage id="SE-196.PopUp6.Question.34" />: null}
        </QuestionCheckBox>
      </CheckboxGroup>
```

Working Example

[image: Edit oj6vox56]

Comment: Yes, mean I will print the inner html when I check one of CheckBox.

Comment: Do you mean you want to check only one checkbox? Something like radio buttons?

Comment: I want to show inner html, mean the formatted message text inside each CheckBox.

Comment: Okay, you mean the same what I did above but in a different way. Do I'm right?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a traditional kind of `<input type="checkbox" ... />` here, but something else we could only to guess what does `Checkbox` component mean. So, try

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={e => { console.log('Test') }} />
```

Does it work?

Comment: Your way work, but I am using `CheckBox` from `antd`, can you check again, thanks.